# What is the difference between skipWhile and filter in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

As title suggest, both function seems to have similar effect and return emit nothing when predicate does not match. It looks like skipWhile is the reverse of filter ?

Comment: From the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-skipWhile): `skipWhile` "... emits *all further source items* as soon as the condition becomes false"

Answer (score 0):

As @cartant says

> skipWhile "... emits all further source items as soon as the condition becomes false"

Note that `skipWhile` takes a predicate (expression that returns a boolean).

In addition there is also `skipUntil`, which this takes an observable and values will be skipped until that observable emits **anything**.

So sometimes the following can be useful (pan is a hammerjs event btw.):

```
  // When event.deltaX reaches 20 emit true to indicate a threshold is reached
  const thresholdReached$ = pan$.pipe(map(e => Math.abs(e.deltaX) > 20 ), first(v => v), shareReplay(1));

  // Emit all events, but skip them until the first time that thresholdReached$ emits
  const panMove$ = pan$.pipe(skipUntil(thresholdReached$));
```

Important to realize that the observable passed to `skipUntil` can emit **any** value to trigger the skipping to stop. It doesn't have to be a 'truthy' value.

So if you have `var b = new BehaviorSubject(false)` then `skipUntil(b)` will immediately stop skipping and you will quickly get very confused!